# Thread Safe removing directories in python

Tags: python-3.x, thread-safety

shutil.rmtree is a recommended way to remove directories in python. Just wondering is it thread safe?  If not, is there any example how to make removing directories thread safe?

```
class DeleteResource:
    def remove_single_folder(self, dir_to_remove):
        """
        :param dir_to_remove: directory to be removed
        """
        try:
            logger.info("Dir to remove " + dir_to_remove)
            shutil.rmtree(dir_to_remove)
        except OSError as error_details:
            logger.error("Removing of directory " + dir_to_remove +
                         " failed: " + str(error_details))
            raise
        logger.info("Dir " + dir_to_remove + " was removed")


    def remove_all_folder_with_prefix(self, prefix):
        """
        remove all contents of directory based on prefix
        :param prefix:
        :return: number of single folders being removed
        """
        num_files_removed = 0
        dir_list = glob.glob(prefix + "*")
        try:
            for dir in dir_list:
                remove_single_folder(dir)
                num_files_removed += 1
        except OSError:
            raise
        return num_files_removed
```

When the above class is being used, it'll be like

```
prefix = '/opt/recorded/'
delete_resource = DeleteResource()
delete_resource.remove_all_folder_with_prefix(prefix)
```

So I need to wrap up the class in such a way that for above use case, it's thread safe.

Comment: There are no threads here, why would it be thread-unsafe?

Comment: I have other methods saving and editing contents under each directory. Just want to make sure this class do not remove directories that are in progress of being updated.

Comment: It depends on your other code (which you haven't posted here). If you are running those other methods in one thread and this method in another thread, then you need to ensure thread-safety. But all of this - outside of the code that you've posted here. You cannot post a "threadless" code and expect us to guess how you are using it in order to determine whether your overall program is thread-safe.

Comment: Other code will be on another thread. It's a big project. There should be a way to make the code I posted here thread safe. This class is relatively independent.

Comment: As it stands, there is nothing here to insinuate anything about threads. The thread-safety of your code depends on how you are using it, not in how it is written. Not sure I can make it any clearer than what I already have.

Comment: I see, just updated the question.

Comment: Yeah, well, you seem to be ignoring my point. Again - the code that you've posted provides no information whatsoever about threads in your program. For example, will this code be executed from one thread, while your other code be executed from another thread? As it stands, there is no threading issue here.

Comment: I think @james is looking for something similar to `os.makedirs(file_path,exist_ok=True)`. I don't see why it is such a ridiculous question.